# Remember size of Dock widget on toggle view

Tags: python, pyside2, qdockwidget

I have two dock widgets in my QApplication widget.
On each widget toggle view action is called.So that it hides and shows when I check and uncheck the dock widget in menu options.`

On toggle, dock widget are not taking the size which they had before being toggled.

How can I go ahead and implement this?

following the minimal code which produces the same problem.

```
 import sys
 from PySide2.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QAction, qApp,QApplication,QDockWidget,QWidget
 from PySide2.QtGui import QIcon
 from PySide2.QtCore import Qt

 class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()

       self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

       menubar = self.menuBar()
       fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&Funcionalities')

       dockwindow1 = QDockWidget("dock1",self)
       dockwindow1.setWidget(QWidget())
       fileMenu.addAction(dockwindow1.toggleViewAction())
       self.setCentralWidget(dockwindow1)

       dockwindow2 = QDockWidget("dock2",self)
       fileMenu.addAction(dockwindow2.toggleViewAction())
       self.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, dockwindow2)


       self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
       self.setWindowTitle('Simple menu')
       self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  ex = Example()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())`
```

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Hi eyllanesc, I have added the code. Look into it and see if you could help me out here. Thank you